# Nginx FastCGI caching with laravel blank page

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I am trying to implement `nginx fastcgi` caching with my `laravel` site but I'm getting a blank white page.

I've checked `laravel`'s and `nginx`'s logs and they show no errors or even access logs but the cache does get stored in the directory it's supposed to.

I have tried the same caching directives with a `wordpress` install on the same server which works flawlessly. I'm just wondering if there are specific `nginx` cache directives that need to be used for `laravel` and also if anyone can recommend a better alternative for caching for `laravel`.

here's my server conf:

```
    fastcgi_cache_path /tmp/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=MYAPP:100m inactive=60m;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name site.com www.site.com;

        root /var/www/site/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        set $no_cache 0;


        charset utf-8;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        access_log off;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/myapp-error.log error;

        sendfile off;

        client_max_body_size 100m;

        location ~ \.php$ {

            fastcgi_cache MYAPP;
            fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m; 

            fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD; 
            add_header X-Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
            fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;  
            fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache; 

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please take a look at https://github.com/jiangwenyuan/nuster, a high performance cache server based on HAProxy